# Trying to apply formula to a date column in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have this `df` with thousands of rows from which one of the columns is `date`:

The `df.head()` shows:

```
        id_code                       texto                   date
0   ZZZZZZZZZZZZ         ha tenido su corrección         2019-03-31
0   WWWWWWWWWWWW         cierra la venta de sus plans    2019-03-29
0   XXXXXXXXXXXX         se han reunido en ferraz        2019-03-26
0   AAAAAAAAAAAA         marca es buen periodico         2019-03-12
```

I would like to apply the following formula to the `date` column :

```
initial_date=(pd.to_datetime("today")- pd.DateOffset(years=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
final_date=pd.to_datetime("today").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

df["ponderacion"]=1-(final_date-pd.to_datetime(df.date))/(final_date-initial_date)
```

however when returning the `df` outputs:

```
ValueError: format number 1 of "b'2019-04-15'" is not recognized
```

Should I `.decode('UTF-8')` the `date.values` to turn them  into str and then to datetime?

If that was the case, when I when tried to decode the `date.values` outputs :

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Could anyone give me some light on how could I overcome this issue and apply the desired formula to `df.date`?

Comment: Looks like you were trying to do `date.values.decode('UTF-8')` and that didn't work because `date.values` is an `np.array`. Try to do `date.apply(lambda x: x.decode('UTF-8'))`.

Comment: Can you post your `df.head().to_dict()`

Comment: {'id_code': {0: 'AAAAAAAAAAAA'}, 'texto': {0: 'marca es buen periodico'}, 'date': {0: '2019-03-12'}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of your problem is that you keep date values as strings.

After creation of your DataFrame, you should first convert `date`
column from string to `datetime`:

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

Then you can compute initial and final dates:

```
final_date = pd.to_datetime('today')
initial_date = final_date - pd.DateOffset(years=1)
```

Note the sequence:

- First compute `final_date`, **without** conversion to string.
- Then compute `initial_date` as one year before `final_date`.

Otherwise there is some difference in fractional part of second.

And the final step is to compute your column:

```
df['ponderacion'] = 1 - (final_date - df.date)/(final_date - initial_date)
```

also **without** conversion to string.

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply` to convert bytes to strings:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.date.apply(str, encoding='ascii'))
```

It applies the function specified (`str` in this case) to each element of the `Series`, and it is possible to specify arguments to the function (`encoding='ascii'` here).

Comment: Hi @aparpara thank you for your help, it outputs TypeError: decoding str is not supported

Comment: @ge00rge, Hm.. what does `print(type(df.date[0]))` print?

Comment: it outputs : class 'pandas.core.series.Series'

Comment: @ge00rge, really? Didn't you forget `[0]`?

Comment: no, I included it. Making a ´print(df.date[0])´ outputs a ´dtype: object ´'with all the column ´dates´.

Comment: @ge00rge, so sorry, I can't understand what is the type of your `date` column. Looks like it is a `Series` of `Series`?! Than you should have made some error constructing your data frame.